# How to close a Voila instance after shutting down kernel

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython, voila

After running a voila command in the anaconda command line I can't seem to regain access to the terminal afterwards. Closing the browser tab will shut down the kernel, but the command prompt remains inoperable. I have tried all the common shortcuts I can think of but nothing short of opening a new command prompt works.

Steps to reproduce

1. Open a notebook in voila using `voila notebook.ipynb`
2. Close the browser tab it opens
3. Kernel closes ([Voila] Kernel shutdown:xxxxxxxx)
4. Command line doesn't return, console remains unusable